# Write to cloudsql in Google DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataflow

I am processing data using Google DataFlow is there any way to write the results to cloudsql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a built-in way of doing this, but you can use the [Sink API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/Sink.java) to write to arbitrary external systems.

Edit: The Sink API is likely overkill for writing to cloudsql; you can just directly make insert calls from a DoFn.

Comment: Thanks danielm. Is it a good practice to write to cloudsql from dataflow ?

Comment: Sure, you can write to any external data storage system you need from Dataflow.  Depending on your usecase, writing to BigQuery may also work, and Dataflow supports that out of the box.

Comment: I wouldn't say that SinkAPI is overkill, since it allows you to write to CloudSQL in a transaction - either everything is saved or nothing.